# Подскажите какой оператор надо перегрузить

Tags: c++, map

У меня есть `std::map<std::string, std::any> mymap`, и я хотел был сделать так что бы такое выражение работало  `bool test = mymap["test"]` и не писать каждый раз `any_cast<bool>`, подскажите какой оператор надо перегрузить и у кого.

Comment: Никакой, для извлечения значения из `any` придется всегда использовать `any_cast`.

Comment: Во-первых, это не выражение, а объявление. Во-вторых, нет, именно в такой постановке задачи ничего перегрузить не получится. Что-то дополнительно писать все равно придется.

Comment: Думаю, тут проще всего запилить свою обертку над `std::any`...

Answer (score -3):

Перегрузить не выйдет. Лучший вариант - написать обёртку для sdt::any. Но самый простой вариант - использовать макросы:

```
#define TO_BOOL(_x,_key) std::any_cast<bool>(_x[_key])
#define MYMAP_TO_BOOL(_key) TO_BOOL(mymap, _key)
...
bool test = MYMAP_TO_BOOL("test");
```

Comment: Не надо грязи. Нормальная функция `bool mymapToBool(const std::map<std::string, std::any>& mymap, const std::string& key)` будет намного предсказуемее

Comment: Чем менее предсказуемы макросы?

Comment: Ну например тем, что нет проверок типов аргументов. Чем не угодили обычные функции?

Comment: Конечно же есть проверки типов, только шагом дальше. Функции угодили всем, но не стоит забывать и про остальные возможности языка. Не понимаю, чем макросы не угодили.